# I can ping my centOS virtual machine but I cant access its shared folders

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtualbox, samba

so this is the setup:

I have a Windows XP installed, VirtualBox and a centOS 6.2 virtual machine.
I installed Samba, and currently, my VM and host Windows are in the same subnet.
I can ping my VM from Windows and vice versa. 
I have a created a shared folder via Samba like this:

```
[Share]
   path = /home/share
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   create mode = 0777
   directory mode = 0777
   share modes = yes
```

**I followed a full tutorial [here](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=samba&f=1)*

My problem now is that, when I try to access such folder like this \192.xx.xxx.xxx\home\share (192.xx.xxx.xxx is the IP address of my VM) from Windows "Run",
Windows can't find it.

P.S. I've turned off my Windows Firewall (although Trend Micro personal firewall is still on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, I changed the iptables, and smb.conf to allow my Host IP address to access my guest. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Just met the same problem, would you mind expalin more? thanks